# Why does the shulchan aruch start with how to conduct one's self in the morning and not the night time?

Tags: halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch

The mishnah in brachos goes out of it's way to discuss why it stated with the night time shema b/c in the posuk it says when you lay down and when you rise up.. Why then when it comes to practical halacha the shulchan aruch reverses this and starts with the day time?

Comment: The Mishna lists Shacharit before Arvit, just like the ShA does. http://sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.4.1 It's just Shema that's the exception.